# xamarin sdk error with xamarin studio

Tags: xamarin

I have downloaded the sdk from here http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other
and extracted to specified folder .
but the error comes that No sdk found at the specified location.
please refer to image.
[image: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/20505/error-xa5205-cannot-find-aapt-exe-please-install-the-android-sdk-build-tools-package]

Comment: please download the image from the link and edit any reputed person on  the stackoverflow

Comment: i also used the zip version from the android developer site but in vain

Answer (score 0):

put both the sdk and ndk files in the same directory.
problem is solved.

Comment: follow link    http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/